# lower and upper bounds on $aA+ bB + cC$ and ${\large{\frac{ab}{l_c}}}+{\large{\frac{bc}{l_a}}}+ {\large{\frac{ca}{l_b}}}$.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-inequalities

Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle.

The goal is to prove:
\begin{align*}
&(a)\;\;\;\pi(2R-r) < aA+ bB + cC < 4(2R-r)\\[2pt]
&\qquad\qquad\text{[where in the above, $A,B,C$ denote the respective radian measures]}\\[6pt]
&(b)\;\;\;\frac{12R}{\pi} < \frac{ab}{l_c}+ \frac{bc}{l_a}+ \frac{ca}{l_b} < 3\pi R\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
where

- $a,b,c$ are the lengths of the sides opposite vertices $A,B,C$, respectively.$\\[4pt]$

  $p$ is the perimeter.$\\[4pt]$

  $r,R$ are the inradius and circumradius, respectively.$\\[4pt]$

  $l_a, l_b,l_c$ are the lengths of the angle bisectors of angles $A,B,C$, respectively.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is unreadable

Comment: What is the meaning of a.A?

Comment: I think $$a,b,c$$ are the sidelengthes and $$A,B,C$$ are the internal angles of the given triangle

Comment: + a,b,c are the lengths of the sides BC, CA, AB of the triangle ABC

Comment: + r is the inradius of the triangle ABC, R is the circumradius of triangle ABC